# When do we use "overwhelming"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

This word is rarely used in Russian. I only know that we can say "overwhelming majority".

**Could you explain the defition of this adjective giving some examples?**

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U! Before we do anything else, please: (1) go to Google.com, (2) type "define:overwhelming", and (3) review the information there. If you need additional help after doing that, please reach back out and let us know, and we'll be happy to review the research that you've done and fill in the blanks. Take care!

Comment: Or try a dictionary!

Comment: How about - "Looking up answer for you on Google and pasting here seems pretty overwhelming"  :-)

Comment: Picture you're in a battle, behind a low stone wall at the top of a hill, and you look down to see the entire Mongolian army charging toward you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

''Overwhelming'' is something that has a great force and effect. It is very intense and consuming.
 For instance, we say ''overwhelming feelings'' or ''to feel overwhelmed'' which means that the feelings we have, are so intense that we become stressed out and even (emotionally) exhausted. 
We also use the particular adjective in phrases like ''overwhelming force'' overwhelming urge'' to describe the strong drive to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Used in the active voice, *to overwhelm* is *to defeat completely by superior force or numbers, or to bury under a mass*.

So an overwhelming majority is one that massively outnumbers the dissenting votes and the abstentions.

An army can overwhelm another army; a tidal wave can overwhelm a seawall or a town, or both.

In the passive voice, *to be overwhelmed*, is *to be overpowered, especially in your thoughts or emotions*, e.g. "I was overwhelmed by a sense of loss"